# How to highlight a table row based on specific search by .addClass in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css

I am able to highlight a particular row of a table by taking a particular search term by the following :

```
if(tableRows[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) != -1){
    particularRow.style.backgroundColor = "#90ee90";
 }
else{
    particularRow.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
}
```

Complete code in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/swarup195/a2aa6jfk/4/
Is there any suggestions for doing it more efficient way e.g. by addClass() method ???

Comment: What do you mean by efficient?

Comment: FYI, `innerText` isn't available on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use :contains (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> One </td>
    <td> Two </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Three </td>
    <td> Four </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="button"> Highlight row </button>
```

JS

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $( "tr:contains('One')" ).addClass( "highlight" );
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight { background: red }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/e7h76dz1/

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you call "efficient". But since you are using jQuery, as a suggestion, you can use the `filter` method:

```
var searchTerm = $("#search input").val().toLowerCase().trim(),
    $list =  $("#carList").children().removeClass('hilight');

if ( searchTerm.length < 2 ) return;

$list.filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) != -1;
}).addClass('hilight');
```

Note that `innerText` is a non-standard property introduced by Internet Explorer browser, you should use the `textContent` property if you want to support the standard browsers. Alternatively you can use the jQuery `text` method (if you are loading jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use one function like this one:

```
function rowHighlight() {
    var searchTerm = $("#search input").val().toLowerCase();
    tableRows = $("#carList").children();

    tableRows.removeClass('highlight');
    if (searchTerm.length > 2) {
        $("#searchIcon").hide();
        tableRows.filter(function(index, element) {
            return $(element).text().indexOf(searchTerm) != -1
        }).addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $("#searchIcon").show();
    }
}
```

I have update you fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2aa6jfk/7/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
tr {
    background-color: transparent;
}
tr.found {
    background-color: #90ee90;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$("#carList tr").each(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("found", $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) != -1);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a2aa6jfk/11/)